# HP Elite Dragonfly G3 webcam not recognized

Tags: hp, webcam, 22.10

I'm running Ubuntu 22.10 on HP Elite dragonfly G3 (2023), not so smoothly.
The webcam is not working (at all), among other problems.

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:0103 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 18a5:0302 Verbatim, Ltd Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lshw -c media : doesn't give anything

$ inxi -Gx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-12.2
    bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.3 driver:
    X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915
    resolution: 1920x1280~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5
    direct render: Yes
```

And compatibility test here: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=2a5d9adcd4

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In order to help you at all, we will need some more information. Please give output of `lsusb`, `lshw -c media` `inxi -Gx`. Add them to your original question (you can [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1464294/edit) it using the link at the bottom of it). Also, please only focus on one issue at a time, and if there are other issues ask a separate question about them.